# Do a server block execution when listening for client connection?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm new to socket programming and I want to create a client/server type of application using winapi. I want my application to be listening for a request from a client, and after serving the client it should continue listening for further requests. But before making an attempt I what to get an overview for understanding of the whole process. My question is when you call listen() on the server side, does the listen() block executes until a client tries to make a connection? 
and after accepting and serving the current client, how does it get back to listening mode for other connections? because from the code I saw on the sites I visited there is no loop which calls listen() again after serving a client, it goes straight to close().

Please forgive me for not adding any code because I want to get basic knowledge before I can attempt it my self.

Comment: There is an asynchronous IO in Windows as well, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapped_I/O

Comment: There are numerous documents and examples on MSDN for how to work with socket programming.

Answer (score 2):

From the diagram as you can see doesn't block on `listen()`
Also, this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-listen) might help you.

From the block you can which are blocking calls
[image: From the block you can which are blocking calls]

Answer (score 1):

> when you call listen() on the server side, does the listen() block executes until a client tries to make a connection?

No.  `listen()` simply opens the listening port and establishes the backlog to hold pending connections, and then it exits.  It is `accept()` instead that blocks waiting for a connection (if you use it in blocking mode, that is, which is the default).

> after accepting and serving the current client, how does it get back to listening mode for other connections?

It is up to you to decide when that happens.  The server will not go back to listening for a connection until you call `accept()` again.  So you need to call `accept()` in a loop for the lifetime of your server.  But, your server design will dictate WHEN you call `accept()`.

If you want to service only 1 client at a time, then you simply have 1 loop that calls `accept()`, services the client in full, closes the accepted socket, and goes back to `accept()`.

But, if you want to service multiple clients in parallel, then you need to accept clients as often as possible, either by calling `accept()` in a dedicated thread or `select()` loop, or by using `AcceptEx()` in the background by Overlapped I/O or an I/O Completion Port.  Once a client has been accepted, you need to then decide whether you want to service the client directly in your `select()` loop, or in its own dedicated thread, or with Overlapped I/O or IOCP.

> from the code I saw on the sites I visited there is no loop which calls listen() again after serving a client, it goes straight to close().

No, there is never a `listen()` loop.  `listen()` is only to be called once, when opening the server port.  But you do need an `accept()` loop instead to accept clients.

> Please forgive me for not adding any code because I want to get basic knowledge before I can attempt it my self.

Literally, there are TONS of socket tutorals available online, and detailed WinSock documentation and examples on MSDN.  All of them cover this topic.